# Rank values in a dataset row

Tags: matlab

I have a dataset of stock prices called 'stocks'. Each column is a different stock. Each row is the date of the stock prices.

How can I rank the stock price of a given date?

I tried

```
 tiedrank(stocks.yhoo)
```

And it successfully ranked the prices of YHOO stock. However, I would like to rank by row, not column.

Also, when I tried

```
tiedrank(stocks(1,:))
```

or to delete the date column in column 1

```
tiedrank(stocks(1,2:3))
```

I got the error message: Dataset array subscripts must be two-dimensional.

Am I doing something wrong? Or am I better off using matrices?

Comment: it seems that you stocks dataset is of class struct. It will be helpful to you to need to read how to extract data from struct arrays: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/access-data-in-a-structure-array.html , or cast to a cell array and work it from there...

Comment: @natan: It appears not to be a struct, but a [dataset](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/dataset.html) array.

Comment: @Jonas, sorry you are right... I thought only structs are used with var1.field format. When did datasets happen?

Comment: @natan: [2009a](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2009/05/20/from-struct-to-dataset/) at the latest; maybe earlier.

Comment: @Jonas “I became wiser through all my teachers”

Comment: @natan: you're welcome. Even I keep learning from SO!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to rank the stocks according to price at a given date, where dates are rows, and stocks are columns. To use `tiedrank` across a row, you need to convert that part of the dataset to `double`, and then use the output index list to sort:

```
%# create index for sorting
idx = tiedrank( double( stocks(1,:) ));

%# reorder columns with index
sortedStocks = stocks(:,idx);
```

Comment: That worked, thanks! Matlab involves more type casting than I expected.

Comment: The cast is there to convert from dataset to a "standard" array. You're welcome, btw.